# SQL best approach count clicks and form submissions

Tags: sql

I need to count number of clicks on specifics links in my site,and number of sent emails from visitors.

Question is:

I've already a table with products and it's description (which i want to count clicks),i thought I would extend this table and create two fields that make a click count and email sent.But maybe I can do it another way, creating a separate table that contains only two fields that make this count, by referencing the product ID.

What do you think that's the best approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would store the clicks and emails in separate tables, and not add them as new columns to the "products" table.

The data is logically different - "products" should contain the definition of a product. The fact someone's clicked on a link to that product is not part of that definition - it's an entirely separate event. As Ben says, it would likely also have a performance impact.

I can also see the requirement extending in the future - you probably need to be able to track clicks per day, or clicks per user type, or whatever; I'd consider just storing the raw data for clicks and emails in a table, and join it to the product table.

For instance:

```
table CLICK
id (PK)
product_id (FK to products)
date
time
user_id (FK to users, if that exists)
```

insert a record into that table every time someone clicks; to run your reports, you need to join back to product to get the description, and use count() and group by to get the right data out.

Answer (score 2):

If you're table for your products is just **SMALL** you can just add it directly there to avoid **duplication of primary keys in separate tables**, **creation of separate stored procedures that would be used to access your table that would contain the click count and the table that would contain your product information**, you could also **avoid using join statements** whenever you have to make a select statement that would need to the result from both tables and of course you can minimize data redundancy by doing that.

Another FYI a table with two columns are usually cross reference tables that is only ideal for storing relationship between related entities.

Answer (score 1):

Extending the products table with these fields is probably not a good idea, because the click and email counts will be updated very often, resulting in your products table (or at least some rows contained in it) to be read/write locked very often. This could result in a lot of latency when reading from the products table and a slow-down of your site. I would go the separate table route.

Answer (score 1):

Allan's right here. Latency will also be an issue if you are going to seperate the two tables. JOINING TWO TABLES is obviously much slower rather than a simple but very efficient select statement .

I would rather use:

```
 SELECT ProductID, ProductName, ClickCount, Email FROM tblProducts
```

rather than

```
 SELECT p.ProductID, p.ProductName, px.ClickCount, px.EmailCount
 FROM tblProducts p
 INNER JOIN tblProductsXRefClickAndEmail px ON p.ProductID = px.ProductID
```